# Why is there no compile error for my @FunctionalInterface with two methods?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

Is below interface a valid functional interface in Java 8?

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface Normal{
    public abstract String move();
    public abstract String toString() ;
}
```

Why doesn't it give me a compile time error?

Comment: Why doesnt it give me compile time error

Comment: Could you please share your logs of the platform on which you're running your code?

Comment: Interesting question. I don't understand the close votes. But Nitin, please learn how to write good questions. Don't just post code, also put the actual question into your text, not into the headline or into a comment only. And edit questions rather than commenting if you want to add something to the question. I will do that for you this time. Please also be advised to learn how to use code blocks, I also fixed your code formatting.

Comment: In short: **Transitive declaration of methods.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What *Alok* quoted is true, but he overlooked something, which makes his final answer (that the code is invalid) wrong:

The interface has one method `String toString()` which every class already implements, inheriting it from `Object`. I.e. the declared interface method already has an implementation, similar to a default method. Hence, there is no compile error and `Normal` can be used as a functional interface as shown in my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

@FunctionalInterface
interface Normal {
  String move();
  String toString();
}
```

BTW, no need to declare interface methods as `public` because they always are. Same goes for `abstract`.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

public class NormalApp {
  static void doSomething(Normal normal) {
    System.out.println(normal.move());
    System.out.println(normal.toString());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    doSomething(() -> "xxx");
  }
}
```

If you run the driver application, you will see this console log:

```
xxx
de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.NormalApp$$Lambda$1/1530388690@28c97a5
```

Now if you change the method name `toString` to something else, e.g. `toStringX`, you will see that due to the `@FunctionalInterface` there is the expected error message when compiling the class:

```
Unexpected @FunctionalInterface annotation
  de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.Normal is not a functional interface
    multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.Normal
```

Comment: Great answer Kriegaex.

Comment: Great explanation, +1